# R Shiny GGplot reactive graph not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to create a scatter plot in R shiny where the user selects X and Y from columns of a reactive `combodf1()` which was built from other reactives. If you set the input to `x` and `y` and the column names directly, it works, but setting them from `input$metric_a` etc (you can see the names of the choices and `combodf1()`'s cols are the same), the data is not present. Any help here would be really appreciated!

```
 Part of the UI:
          selectInput("metric_a", "metric_a:",
                      c("Buzz" = "buzz",
                        "Aided" = "aided",
                        "Adaware" = "adaware")),

          selectInput("metric_b", label = ("Metric B"), 
                  c("Buzz" = "buzz",
                    "Aided" = "aided",
                    "Adaware" = "adaware")),


Part of the server:

       combotest<- reactive({do.call(cbind, list(adaware()$Value, buzz()$Value, aided()$Value))})
      combodf<- reactive({as.data.frame(combotest())})
      # Renaming reactive cols - WORKS, PLYR function
      combodf1<-reactive({rename(combodf(), c("V1"="adaware", "V2"='buzz', 'V3' = 'aided'))})

      # PLOT 

      output$plot2<-renderPlot({
        ggplot(data=combodf1(),aes(x=input$metric_a,y=input$metric_b))+geom_point(colour='red')})

      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, you have to use:

`aes_string` instead of `aes` when your `x` and `y` are `input$` variables in `GGPlot`.

Hope this saves someone some time!